# Position div inside another div without absolute

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've seen a few questions like this around, but no answers worked for me so far. I'm trying to get the inside div on the bottom of the outer div (although not entirely, I want, like, a 5px margin to the bottom), but I can't seem to position it at all without putting the position on absolute. If I do THAT, though, the width and the centering doesn't work anymore.

Is there any way for me to achieve that?

Here's my code:

```js
var height = $('.windows').height()*0.85;
 $('.windows-content').css('height', height);
```

```css
.windows {
 max-width: 900px;
 width: 70%;
 min-height: 300px;
 height: auto;
 box-shadow: -1px -1px 0px 0px #000 inset, 1px 1px 0px 0px #FFF inset, -2px -2px 0px 0px #868A8E inset;
    background-color: #C2C5CA; 
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.windows-content {
 width: 98.5%;
 height: auto;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px 0px #000 inset, -1px -1px 0px 0px #FFF inset;
    background-color: #FFF;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="windows" id="home-window">
  <div class="windows-content"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use flex box to get the result you are looking for

**See code snippet:**

```js
var height = $('.windows').height() * 0.85;
$('.windows-content').css('height', height);
```

```css
.windows {
  max-width: 900px;
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #C2C5CA;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}

.windows-content {
  width: 98.5%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="windows" id="home-window">
  <div class="windows-content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be adding a `padding-bottom` to the `.container` div, and then just create a JS variable capturing this padding value; then the new value for the JS `height` variable should be the initial height minus the forementioned `padding-bottom`. I added a value of `10px`in the code snippet CSS, but you can write there the value you need.

```js
var height = $('.windows').height();

$('.windows-content').css('height', height);

var bottom = height - 5;

var get_padding_bottom = parseInt( $('.windows').css('padding-bottom') , 10);

height -= get_padding_bottom;
```

```css
.windows {
 max-width: 900px;
 width: 70%;
 min-height: 300px;
 box-shadow: -1px -1px 0px 0px #000 inset, 1px 1px 0px 0px #FFF inset, -2px -2px 0px 0px #868A8E inset;
  background-color: #C2C5CA; 
 margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.windows-content {
 width: 98.5%;
 height: auto;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px 0px #000 inset, -1px -1px 0px 0px #FFF inset;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="windows" id="home-window">
  <div class="windows-content"></div>
</div>
```